# Tweepy issues with twitter bot and python

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy, try-except

I have a few twitterbots that I run on my raspberryPi. I have most functions wrapped in a try / except to ensure that if something errors it doesn't break the program and continues to execute.

I'm also using Python's Streaming library as my source of monitoring for the tags that I want the bot to retweet.

Here is an issue that happens that kills the program although I have the main function wrapped in a try/except:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function startBot5 at     0x762fbed0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TwitButter.py", line 151, in startBot5
    '<botnamehere>'
  File "/home/pi/twitter/bots/TwitBot.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.startFiltering(trackList)
  File "/home/pi/twitter/bots/TwitBot.py", line 54, in startFiltering
    self.myStream.filter(track=tList)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 445, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 361, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 294, in _run
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 263, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 313, in _read_loop
    line = buf.read_line().strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

My setup:
I have a parent class TwitButter.py, that creates an object from the TwitBot.py. These objects are the bots, and they are started on their own thread so they can run independently.

I have a function in the TwitBot that runs the startFiltering() function. It is wrapped in a try/except, but my except code is never triggered.

My guess is that the error is occurring within the Streaming library. Maybe that library is poorly coded and breaks on the line that is specified at the bottom of the traceback.

Any help would be awesome, and I wonder if others have experienced this issue?

I can provide extra details if needed.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Fixed in [github #870](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/870) so update your tweepy copy?

Comment: Big thanks!!! I have made the changes so it should be all good! I appreciate the quick response! and the noob I am, I wasn't aware that I can modify these libraries...

Comment: @gz did you want to answer the question so I can accept it. It appears to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually is problem in tweepy that was fixed by [github #870](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/pull/870) in 2017-04. So, should be resolved by updating your local copy to latest master.

What I did to discover that:

- Did a web search to find the tweepy source repo.
- Looked at `streaming.py` for context on the last traceback lines.
- Noticed the most recent change to the file was the same problem.

I'll also note that most of the time you get a traceback from deep inside a Python library, the problem comes from the code calling it incorrectly, rather than a bug in the library. But not always. :)